# Stereo to mono amp solution with mono bridge

Tags: amplifier, class-d

I have these stereo amplifiers - [Adafruit 20W](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1752) and [Sure Electronics 15W](http://www.parts-express.com/sure-electronics-aa-ab32155-2x15w-at-4-ohm-ta2024-class-d-audio-amplifier-board-only--320-330).

If I connect this [passive stereo to mono bridge](http://www.stufinnis.co.uk/stereotomono.html) at its output, will it technically be a good solution? Will the amps work correctly?

I have searched and searched for modules which can take in stereo inputs and output mono, but there isn't just any available.

Anyway, is there any other technique to help with this. Or any other amp which can support simple twisting of wires to get it play only mono from a stereo.

*PS - Got a 15W driver with 4 ohm. Need to work with 4 ohm.*

Comment: You probably should have gotten a stereo amplifier that was designed to be bridged to mono. Then it's easy -- essentially your "simple twisting of wires." But you can also get an active phase-splitter or phase-splitting audio transformer. Or you could go here: http://sound.whsites.net/project20.htm

Comment: The Adafruit is already bridge tied and it looks like the Sure amp is the same so don't try and bridge between left and right outputs - therein lies the path to the magic blue smoke. If you split the mono between L+R inputs you feed each channel with the same signal so you get mono at both outputs.

Comment: So if the source, like from the phone jack, itself is connected with that passive bridge, then I just need to hook a mono to mono amp at one of its output side and leave the other output of the bridge as is, and that would get us to a solution?